# Question regarding two transistors

Tags: transistors

How do I start with this question?

There are 2 transistors which are more complicated and I have no clue on how to start working on it.

---

> The transistors shown in the figure below operate in the active region and have \$ \beta=100\$ and \$V_{BE}=0.7\$ V. Determine \$I_C\$ and \$V_{CE}\$ for each transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdyTVo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Start by working out how much base current flows into Q1. Hint: 15V supply, 0.7 base emitter voltage 1.43M resistor. I can see it's 10uA without pressing a button.

Answer (score 1):

The 1.43M resistor will provide you Q1 Base-Emitter current (and then Ic), with which you can determinate Q2 Base voltage. Then, Ic and Vce for each transistor is straight ahead.

Comment: Then you can further refine Vce for Q1 to account for Ib into Q2.